# ul disappers when hovered over it

Tags: html, css

here's my Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/3mh8m/
my problem is that when i hover over the "Nokia" list item the submenu appears having the image but when i leave the "Nokia" list item and go to hover over the image in it's sub menu the submenu disapears but it should not , can someone help me , thanks.

here's my little code because site isn't letting me post my question without adding code.

```
<body>
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="navbar">
<li class="nav_items"><a href="#">Apple</a>
        <ul class="subnavapple">                                
            <li>            
                <a href='sam.html'><img src="logo.png" width="100" height="100">
                <div class='prodinfo'>
                Samsung Galaxy S5<br>
                Price:AED 2599.00</div>
                </a>                                            
            </li>                       
        </ul>           
</li>           

<li><a href="#">HTC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nokia</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: did you mean "Apple" ?

Comment: oh sorry , yes i meant apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply include a style that changes `display` to `block` for the subnav when the subnav itself is being hovered over, as well as when the navigation item is being hovered over:

Change the following piece of your code:

```
.nav_items :hover ~.subnavapple{
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px #595359;
}
```

to this:

```
.nav_items :hover ~.subnavapple, .subnavapple:hover {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px #595359;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3mh8m/1/)

By applying those same styles to `.subnavapple:hover` too, the subnav won't hide when your mouse leaves the `<a>` which is selected by `.nav_items :hover`. The reason it disappears in your example is because your mouse leaves the navigation item, so the `:hover` pseudo-class does no longer apply to the `<a>`.

Comment: @user3624126 if this solved your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer.